# What is the future of SIEM tools?

Tags: siem

Do SIEM tools have a future or will everything move to 100% automation? Will an analyst need to monitor and analyse the collected data in the future or will this be automated? How will SIEMs tools be in the future?

Comment: This question is too broad and undefined and requires a lot of speculation. How far in the future? Is there an alternative to SIEM that you are thinking about? Can you narrow the question down at all?

Comment: SIEM does not have a future and here is why, 1) SIEM killers, such as Chronicle Security's Backstory product, 2) Big Data and SIEM do not work, nor scale long-term. Automation is not the answer for SIEM, nor Security Operations. Security Operations must/will move to a NCWF model, where current/modern aspects are broken down to more-granular roles and functions. This has already started and will take about 5 years to go fully mainstream.

Comment: The tools we use for SIEM today will be replaced by platforms such as AWS Kinesis (or LogStash-like mechanisms) filtered to Spark Structured Streaming with Spark SQL ETL pushing DataFrames to Parquet files on a structured DFS or S3 (or S3-like). Spark Structured Streaming will also push out to an alerting engine that looks a lot more like streamalert.io and a lot less like commercial SIEM/SIM we've known for 2 decades now.

Answer (score 2):

> Does SIEM has future

Yes.

> like is it going 100% automation

No.

> like an Analyst need to monitor and analyse?

Yes, but hopefully less than they do today.

> Or how the SIEM tools will be in future?

More automated analysis, but still reliant on humans to discriminate between false and true positives.